# static map line between points

Tags: java, bing-maps

I can't find a way to show on a static map the line between 2 points.

I can see that in javascript you use something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795475/how-to-draw-path-or-line-two-pushpins-in-bing-map).

I am trying something like:

```
https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/road/33,-79.1;34,-78/7?mapSize=600,300&color=red&format=png&key=thekey
```

but just shows the map without any points or lines.

I can't find where and how to put the 2 coordinate points.At what point exactly?

Comment: How are you trying to output it? Image / Web UI / Swing / JavaFX ...

Comment: @jrtapsell:I am saving image as an outputStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bing Maps REST services do not support line drawing other than a route path (which is calculated by Bing Maps). You can have the image display the points on the map as pushpins as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff701724.aspx

If you want to draw a line on the image you will need to do this afterwards in your code. I have an old code sample that used the Bing Maps SOAP services (same idea as REST just a different way of requesting the image). Getting this to work with the REST services would be fairly easy. https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/ve-imagery-service-polygons-and-polylines/

That said, you likely will find using the JavaScript API much easier and would provide a lot more options. If you are building a desktop app, you can host the map inside of a web browser control easily.